# How to remove empty values from object using lodash

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

I have an object with several properties and I would like to remove objects/nested objects that are empty, using lodash. What is the best way to do this?

```
Let template = {
      node: "test",
      representation: {
        range: { }
      },
      transmit: {
        timeMs: 0
      }
    };
```

to

```
template = {
      node: "test",
      transmit: {
        timeMs: 0
      }
    };
```

I tried something like this, but I am lost.

```
Utils.removeEmptyObjects = function(obj) {
  return _.transform(obj, function(o, v, k) {
    if (typeof v === 'object') {
      o[k] = _.removeEmptyObjects(v);
    } else if (!_.isEmpty(v)) {
      o[k] = v;
    }
  });
};
_.mixin({
  'removeEmptyObjects': Utils.removeEmptyObjects
});
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can achieve this through several steps:

1. Use [pickBy()](https://lodash.com/docs#pickBy) to pick object key-values, using the [isObject()](https://lodash.com/docs#isObject) predicate.
2. Use [mapValues()](https://lodash.com/docs#mapValues) to recursively call `removeEmptyObjects()`, note that it would only invoke this function with objects.
3. Remove all empty objects that are found after the `mapValues()` using [omitBy()](https://lodash.com/docs#omitBy) with an [isEmpty()](https://lodash.com/docs#isObject) predicate.
4. Assign all primitive values from the object all over again using [assign()](https://lodash.com/docs#assign) for assignment, and `omitBy()` with an `isObject()` predicate.

---

```
function removeEmptyObjects(obj) {
  return _(obj)
    .pickBy(_.isObject) // pick objects only
    .mapValues(removeEmptyObjects) // call only for object values
    .omitBy(_.isEmpty) // remove all empty objects
    .assign(_.omitBy(obj, _.isObject)) // assign back primitive values
    .value();
}
```

```js
function removeEmptyObjects(obj) {
  return _(obj)
    .pickBy(_.isObject)
    .mapValues(removeEmptyObjects)
    .omitBy(_.isEmpty)
    .assign(_.omitBy(obj, _.isObject))
    .value();
}

_.mixin({
  removeEmptyObjects: removeEmptyObjects
});

var template = {
  node: "test",
  representation: {
    range: {}
  },
  transmit: {
    timeMs: 0
  }
};

var result = _.removeEmptyObjects(template);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It does not work with array of objects. Can you modify this for http://jsfiddle.net/alpeshprajapati/fy3uLpw5/. Instead of array of objects, It returns object of objects.

Comment: If it's an array of objects then use [`lodash#map`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map) along with this function.. e.g. `var result = _.map(array, removeEmptyObjects);`

Comment: I didnt understand this, can you modify jsfiddle ?

Comment: My obj contains nested array of object e.g. [and] key. You can check 'result' in console which has object of object for 'and' key under rules.

Comment: Here it isn't elegant, but it should solve your problem. http://jsfiddle.net/ryeballar/n0afoxdu/

Answer (score 8):

To remove undefined, null, and empty string from an object with no nested objects

```
_.omitBy(object, (v) => _.isUndefined(v) || _.isNull(v) || v === '');
```

for nested objects, you can make a recursive function doing that

It will remove empty Objects, empty array, null, undefined, empty strings with any level...

```
removeEmpty(obj) {
        let finalObj = {};
        Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
            if (obj[key] && typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
                const nestedObj = removeEmpty(obj[key]);
                if (Object.keys(nestedObj).length) {
                    finalObj[key] = nestedObj;
                }
            } else if (obj[key] !== '' && obj[key] !== undefined && obj[key] !== null) {
                finalObj[key] = obj[key];
            }
        });
        return finalObj;
    }
```

**UPDATE 11-4-2022**

Based on @RahulSoni comment I just fixed converting of arrays to objects. Now everything should be handled. Please let me know if you have any other comments

```
removeEmpty(obj) {
    const finalObj = {};
    Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
      if (obj[key] && typeof obj[key] === 'object' && !Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
        const nestedObj = this.removeEmpty(obj[key]);
        if (Object.keys(nestedObj).length) {
          finalObj[key] = nestedObj;
        }
      } else if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
        if (obj[key].length) {
          obj[key].forEach((x) => {
            const nestedObj = this.removeEmpty(x);
            if (Object.keys(nestedObj).length) {
              finalObj[key] = finalObj[key] ? [...finalObj[key], nestedObj] : [nestedObj];
            }
          });
        }
      } else if (obj[key] !== '' && obj[key] !== undefined && obj[key] !== null) {
        finalObj[key] = obj[key];
      }
    });
    return finalObj;
  }
```

Example:

```
   const obj = {
            a: '',
            aa: null,
            aaa: undefined,
            aaaa: 'aaaa',
            aaaaa: 0,
            aaaaaa: 1,
            aaaaaaa: 2,
            aaaaaaaa: true,
            aaaaaaaaa: false,
            emptyObj: {},
            emptyArray: [],
            array: [
                {
                    a: '',
                    aa: null,
                    aaa: undefined,
                    aaaa: 'aaaa',
                    aaaaa: 0,
                    aaaaaa: 1,
                    aaaaaaa: 2,
                    aaaaaaaa: true,
                    aaaaaaaaa: false,
                    emptyObj: {},
                    emptyArray: [],
                    obj: {
                        a: '',
                        aa: null,
                        aaa: undefined,
                        aaaa: 'aaaa',
                        aaaaa: 0,
                        aaaaaa: 1,
                        aaaaaaa: 2,
                        aaaaaaaa: true,
                        aaaaaaaaa: false,
                        emptyObj: {},
                        emptyArray: [],
                    },
                },
                {
                    a: '',
                    aa: null,
                    aaa: undefined,
                    aaaa: 'aaaa',
                    aaaaa: 0,
                    aaaaaa: 1,
                    aaaaaaa: 2,
                    aaaaaaaa: true,
                    aaaaaaaaa: false,
                    emptyObj: {},
                    emptyArray: [],
                    obj: {
                        a: '',
                        aa: null,
                        aaa: undefined,
                        aaaa: 'aaaa',
                        aaaaa: 0,
                        aaaaaa: 1,
                        aaaaaaa: 2,
                        aaaaaaaa: true,
                        aaaaaaaaa: false,
                        emptyObj: {},
                        emptyArray: [],
                    },
                },
            ],
            b: {
                a: '',
                aa: null,
                aaa: undefined,
                aaaa: 'aaaa',
                aaaaa: 0,
                aaaaaa: 1,
                aaaaaaa: 2,
                aaaaaaaa: true,
                aaaaaaaaa: false,
                emptyObj: {},
                emptyArray: [],
                c: {
                    a: '',
                    aa: null,
                    aaa: undefined,
                    aaaa: 'aaaa',
                    aaaaa: 0,
                    aaaaaa: 1,
                    aaaaaaa: 2,
                    aaaaaaaa: true,
                    aaaaaaaaa: false,
                    emptyObj: {},
                    emptyArray: [],
                },
            },
        };

        const finalObj = removeEmpty(obj);
        console.log('finalObj After remove', finalObj);
```

Comment: This does not handle nested objects

Comment: I have updated my answer for nested objects but without using lodash

Comment: @Gouda please let me know if that works for u.

Comment: @AmrOmar handles nested but converts arrays to objects.

Comment: @RahulSoni please provide us with an example as I can't reproduce that.

Comment: @AmrOmar your very own example does that, try and execute it! Key 'array' would turn into an object.

Comment: @RahulSoni I fixed it. please check and let me know if you have any other comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this one (typescript) also works with arrays and supports treeshaking:

```js
import flow from "lodash/fp/flow";
import pickBy from "lodash/fp/pickBy";
import mapValues from "lodash/fp/mapValues";
import map from "lodash/fp/map";
import assign from "lodash/fp/assign";
import { default as fpOmitBy } from "lodash/fp/omitBy";
import { default as fpFilter } from "lodash/fp/filter";
import { isArray, isEmpty, isObject, omitBy } from "lodash-es";

export const compact = (obj) => !isObject(obj) ? obj : isArray(obj) ? compactArray(obj) : compactObject(obj);

const compactArray = (arr) => flow(
  map(compact),
  fpFilter(x => !isEmpty(x) || !isObject(x)),
)(arr)

const compactObject = (obj) =>  flow(
  pickBy(isObject),
  mapValues(compact), 
  fpOmitBy(isEmpty),
  assign(omitBy(obj, isObject)),
)(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modified version of Amr's function that solves an issue I was having with it where it give it input like this:

```
const data = {
                    key1: 'value1',
                    topLevelKey1: {
                    key2: {}
                    },
                    key3: 'value3',
                    updates: [
                    { toDeleteKey: {}, fullKey: 'has a value' },
                    { toDeleteKey2: {}, fullKey2: 'has a value',
                    media: [
                        "https://thisisalink.com",
                        "https://thisisanotherlink.com",
                      ]},
                    ],
                };
```

It would treat the strings in media like objects and split them out like:

```
"media":[{"0":"h","1":"t","2":"t","3":"p","4":"s"...
```

```
function removeEmpty(obj: Record<string, any>): Record<string, any> {
    const finalObj: Record<string, any> = {};
    Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
      if (obj[key] && typeof obj[key] === 'object' && !Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
        const nestedObj = removeEmpty(obj[key]);
        if (Object.keys(nestedObj).length) {
          finalObj[key] = nestedObj;
        }
      } else if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
        if (obj[key].length) {
          finalObj[key] = obj[key].map((x) => {
            if (typeof x === 'object' && !Array.isArray(x)) {
              return removeEmpty(x);
            } else {
              return x;
            }
          });
        }
      } else if (obj[key] !== '' && obj[key] !== undefined && obj[key] !== null) {
        finalObj[key] = obj[key];
      }
    });
    return finalObj;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm updating this for those who search for a solution to this problem in the future.

lodash provides an easier way to do this.

_.compact(arrayName) will remove all the empty/undefined/null values from an Array using lodash

Answer (score -3):

You could use `_.pick` to choose only the properties you want, as in

```
var desiredTemplate = _.pick(template, ['node','transmit']);
```

Otherwise, as far as I can tell, lodash has nothing built in that can recursively remove empty objects/arrays from an object.