# How can I project an object only if document has a specific field in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate, aggregation

I have the following project:

```
{
    '$project': {
        '_id': 1,
        'applicationIds': {
            'type': 'linux',
            'refId': '$applicationIds'
        },
        'configurationIds': {
            'type': 'linux',
            'refId': '$configurationIds'
        }
    }
}
```

As long as there is at least one record in `$configurationIds` I will get something like this:

```
{
    'type': 'linux',
    'refId': ObjectId('...')
}
```

And same with `$applicationIds`..

The issue arises when there are no records in `$configurationIds` or `$applicationIds` then I get this:

```
{
    'type': 'linux'
}
```

I don't want this, if there are no `$applicationIds`, I just want the object to be empty.

Btw I do an `$unwind` on `$applicationIds` (with preserveNullAndEmptyArrays) just before this stage so there can only be either one or no applicationIds in each document. Same goes for applicationIds.

Comment: so there can only be either one or no applicationIds in each document. is it same for  he other field

Comment: Yes, both fields.

Comment: so before projecting is it like `{    "_id": 1,    "applicationIds": ObjectId(blabla)}`. also if no object id there is no field

Comment: Yes, that's all correct., and that's the case for both applicationIds and configurationIds.

Comment: again if i understand corect u need sommething like `{
    "_id": 1,
    "applicationIds": {
      "refId": ObjectId("adfghjk"),
      "type": "linux"
    },
    "configurationIds": {}
  }` if configurationIds field not exists?

Comment: Yes, or you don’t even need the configuratuonIds if it doesn’t exist.. just project it if it exists exists, that would be fine too if it’s easier..

Comment: can you check the below one i just assumed you need an empty object if doesn't exist

Comment: i gave test cases for both the cases you mentioned. you can have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can write a condition to check if the field is missing or not. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46088667/13583510) post shows a way to check that and if doesn't exists project an empty object

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      applicationIds: {
        $cond: {
          if: { $ne: [ { $type: "$applicationIds" }, "missing" ] },
          then: { type: "linux", refId: "$applicationIds" },
          else: {}
        }
      },
      configurationIds: {
        $cond: {
          if: { $ne: [ { $type: "$configurationIds" }, "missing" ] },
          then: { type: "linux", refId: "$configurationIds" },
          else: {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gUU5CFZ9JcR)

if you don't want the non existing field after projecting as well instead of the empty object you can use `$$REMOVE`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46047522/13583510) post has some example usage of it

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      applicationIds: {
        $cond: {
          if: { $ne: [ { $type: "$applicationIds" }, "missing" ] },
          then: { type: "linux", refId: "$applicationIds" },
          else: "$$REMOVE"
        }
      },
      configurationIds: {
        $cond: {
          if: { $ne: [ { $type: "$configurationIds" }, "missing" ] },
          then: { type: "linux", refId: "$configurationIds" },
          else: "$$REMOVE"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9ODrBFXxrAy)

Answer (score 0):

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([
   {
      $project: {
         fieldToProject: {
            $cond: {
               if: { $exists: ["$specificField", true] },
               then: "$specificField",
               else: null
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

Comment: did you test this. says exists doesnt work here

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).