# MongoDB update pipeline syntax for removing fields with search pattern

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Given an array of *Timesheets* like (simplified, it has +70 fields):

```
const timesheets = [
  { "_id": "123", "WORKDATE": "2023-06-06", "ACTIVITY": 0 },
  { "_id": "456", "WORKDATE": "0000-00-00", "ACTIVITY": 5 }
]
```

I run pipeline below with the goal of removing existing fields that are blank; ie in the form of empty string, empty array or zero. That works fine with the `$replaceRoot` step.

In addition, I want to remove certain date fields based on pattern search. See `unset` function.

**How can I move `unset` to pipeline code?** Is there a similar statement as `.test()` in javascript to use?

```
  const handleWindow = (async (timesheets) => {
    if(!Array.isArray(timesheets) || timesheets.length === 0) return;

    const unset = (obj) => (
        // Return an array with keys for unset in pipeline; try to find intial date fields.
        Object.entries(obj).filter(([key, value]) => ( 
            value === '0000-00-00' && /(DAT|LAST|AT|FIN|START)/.test(key) 
        )).map((a) => a.shift())
    );
    
    // Upsert timesheets; remove blank values
    const bulkOperations = timesheets.map(timesheet => ({
        updateOne: { 
            filter: { _id: timesheet._id }, 
            update: [
                { $set: timesheet },
                { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $arrayToObject: {
                    $filter: { input: { $objectToArray: '$$ROOT' }, 
                    cond: { $not: { $in: ['$$this.v', ['', [], 0] ]}} }}}}},
              { $unset: unset(timesheet) }
            ], upsert: true } }
        ));        

        return await context.services.get('mongodb-atlas').db('TimesheetsDB').collection('Timesheets').bulkWrite(bulkOperations);
  
    })(timesheets)
```

Comment: perhaps check this very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46038174/how-to-remove-unwanted-fields-from-output-by-condition

Comment: Thanks, really good information in that question!