# Bigquery STRUCT ARRAY IGNORE NULLS TO JSON

Tags: sql, arrays, json, struct, google-bigquery

I'm generating a .json file output from Bigquery and attempting to only include NON NULL values within an "attributes" array/struct. My below query generates the STRUCT field with all the values including NULLs.

```
WITH t0 AS (
    SELECT 'd1' AS product_code, 'AA|BB' AS f1, '11|22|33' AS f2, NULL AS f3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'd2' AS product_code, 'ZZ' AS f1, '55|66' AS f2, 1 AS f3
)
,t1 AS (
    SELECT
        product_code
        ,SPLIT(f1, '|') AS f1
        ,SPLIT(f2, '|') AS f2
        ,f3
    FROM t0
)
SELECT
    product_code
    ,STRUCT(f1, f2, f3) AS attributes --IGNORE NULLS ?
FROM t1
```

The query returns in json:

```
[
  {
    "product_code": "d1",
    "attributes": {
      "f1": [
        "AA",
        "BB"
      ],
      "f2": [
        "11",
        "22",
        "33"
      ],
      "f3": null
    }
  },
  {
    "product_code": "d2",
    "attributes": {
      "f1": [
        "ZZ"
      ],
      "f2": [
        "55",
        "66"
      ],
      "f3": "1"
    }
  }
]
```

How can I remove `f3` from the `d1` array (`null`) but keep it within `d2`?

Answer (score 1):

**Update 2023:**

Try [JSON_STRIP_NULLS](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#json_strip_nulls) function:

```
SELECT JSON_STRIP_NULLS(JSON '{"a": null, "b": "c"}') AS json_data

/*-----------*
 | json_data |
 +-----------+
 | {"b":"c"} |
 *-----------*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried to replicate your issue, but there is no direct approach to remove f3 from the d1 array in Bigquery. As an alternative, you can refer to this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60627493/16531441), it removes null values from JSON object using node.js. You may apply this JSON parser on the query returns (JSON format) from Bigquery.

Answer (score 0):

Use a JavaScript UDF to output JSON (without nulls) like so:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION
  stripNulls(input JSON)
  RETURNS JSON
  LANGUAGE js AS r"""
  return Object.keys(input).reduce((output, key) => {
    const value = input[key];
    return value !== null ? {...output, [key]: value} : output;
  }, {});
""";

SELECT stripNulls(TO_JSON(STRUCT('a' AS foo, 'b' AS bar, NULL AS biz)));

--> {"bar":"b","foo":"a"}
```